# Convergence of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^k}{e^{kx}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**Question_**

> Does $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^k}{e^{kx}}$$ converge?

Since
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^k}{e^{kx}}=\lim_{t \to \infty} \left({1\over k}\right)^k\frac{t^k}{e^t},$$
what we only have to do is proving that 
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{t^k}{e^t}$$
converges. I think I've seen this form before, but I've never seen the proof. The strategy I've been thinking is to firstly prove the limits when $t$ is a natural number. In other word, prove the convergence as a sequence: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^k}{e^n}, n \in \mathbb {N}$$
Then expand the range of $t$ by using squeeze.

Could you please help me to prove the **first step**, which is to make a sequence and prove it? Thanks for answering my question.

c.f. I tried to demonstrate this in order to determine the convergence of the following series.$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{e^{n \over 3}}$$ 
(The convergence can be also determined by using integral test + partial integration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k <0$ then the limit is $\infty$. If $k=0$ the limit is $1$. If $k >0$ use the fact that $e^{kx} >\frac {(kx)^{N}} {N!}$ where $N$ is an integer  exceeding $k$ to see that the limit is $0$.

Comment: IMO, it is simpler to consider $(\lim_{x\to\infty}x/e^x)^k$.

Answer (score 3):

actually, when k is fixed, we can consider the following indentity.

$\quad$ $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^k}{e^{kx}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{x}{e^x})^k$.

Using the L.Hospital Law, we can get $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^x}=0$.

Hence, if k is positve, then the limit is 0. If k is negative, then the limit is $\infty$. When k=0, then $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: I've learned from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An exercise:

Let $k>0$.

$x:=\log y$, $y \rightarrow \infty;$

$\dfrac{(\log y)^k}{e^{\log (y^k)}}= \dfrac{(\log y)^k}{y^k}=\left (\dfrac{\log y}{y}\right)^k$.

Take the limit.

What happens if $k<0$?

Note: $\log y =\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{y}}(1/t)dt < $

$\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{y}}(1/√t)dt =2√t]_{1}^{y}=$

$2(√y-1)<2√y$.